# Where does the direction vanish when we take scalar product of two vectors?is direction indeterministic?

Tags: vectors

Is it convention that scalar product of vectors produces scalar and vector product producrs vectors.if it is mathematically proved... how can two vectors or direction having physical quantities produce a directionless quantity in scalar product ... where does direction vanish... is it indeterministic?  produce

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it indeterministic"? In general I would recommend you to make your question clearer.

Comment: This is similar to asking “where did the direction go?” when you take the magnitude of a vector, or “where did the negatives go?” when multiplying two negative numbers.

Comment: *if it is mathematically proved* There is nothing to prove here. The scalar and vector product of vectors are useful *definitions*.

Comment: Could you possibly clean up your wording so it is a little more clear what you are asking?

Comment: The label says it all. A scalar has no direction. If you want a direction, use the vector product.

Comment: When we calculate dot poduct between vectors,angle between vectors or directed lines comes into result, but the result is directionless.we are taking projection of B on A then the direction of resultant should be in direction of A.but we know dot product is directionless.is direction really does not matter or we are unable to find.where direction of two vectors vanish?magnitude of vector A is A and magnitude of vector B is B then... if we are simply taking magnitude multiplication in dot

Comment: product then the result of product must be simply AB,why we are cinsidering directions and ignoring it after product.and negative and positive are two directions in one dimension.there also direction not lost

Comment: @PhoenixBirdEduventures What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: G.Smith Sir has said it all when he gave the analogy of magnitude of the vector. Dot product is just multiplication of magnitudes and the cosine of the angle.

Comment: How can two directed lines produce a directionless line? As in dot product two vectors produces a non vector

Comment: @PhoenixBirdEduventures Two directed lines don’t produce an undirected line, they produce a number.

Comment: How can product of two directed lines produce a number or point without direction? Where dors direction vanish?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105009/discussion-between-knight-and-phoenix-bird-eduventures).

Comment: The question is confusing. The question appears to be asking "why do we call the midnight train to Georgia "the midnight train to Georgia"?" Well, what else would we call the train that goes to Georgia at midnight?  What else would we call the product that produces a scalar if not "the scalar product"? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: When you measure your height, where does your hair color vanish?  How can a blonde person produce a height with no hair color at all?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an intuitive visualization taken from
[Better Explained - Vector calculus: Understanding the dot product](https://betterexplained.com/articles/vector-calculus-understanding-the-dot-product/)
(section "Analogies For The Dot Product").

Consider sun-light hitting a solar panel.

The sun-light obviously has a magnitude (the intensity, or power per area,
actually $1.36\text{ kW/m}^2$ in a cloudless sky)
and a direction (the direction of the light rays).
So sun-light intensity is a vector. Let's call it $\vec{I}$.

The solar panel also has a magnitude (the area, measurable in $\text{m}^2$)
and a direction (we take the direction perpendicular to the panel).
So the area is a vector too. Let's call it $\vec{A}$.

Now let's assume the light hits the panel not perpendicular,
but at an angle $\theta$ (measured between the light rays and
the panel's normal vector).
We want to know how much sun-light hits the panel.
This power is obviously just a number (measurable in $\text{kW}$).
It doesn't have any direction.
So the power is not a vector, but a scalar.

This power can be calculated from the magnitudes $I$ and $A$
and the angle $\theta$ by
$$P=I A \cos(\theta)$$
or equivalently as the scalar product of the vectors $\vec{I}$ and $\vec{A}$
$$P=\vec{I}\cdot\vec{A}$$

So there is no magic or shortcoming about the direction vanishing.
The scalar product was designed to give a scalar from two vectors.
And there are physical situations (like this example) where we need this.

Answer (score 0):

We can agree that the magnitude of a vector, $||\vec a||$, has no direction. The coordinate free scalar product is defined by:

$$\vec a \cdot \vec b \equiv \frac 1 4 [||(\vec a + \vec b)||^2- ||(\vec a - \vec b)||^2]$$

So it's just the difference between 2 directionless magnitudes (squared).